# MongoDB - Filter Array and Get distinct counts

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

My MongoDB document looks like below:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fb1828a6dbd2e5c533e2378"),
    "email" : "hskasd@gmail.com",
    "fname" : "JOSE",
    "appt" : [ 
        {
            "date" : "12/04/2020",
            "time" : "0900",
        },
        {
            "date" : "12/05/2020",
            "time" : "1000",
        },
    ]
}
```

> Both `appt.date` and `appt.time` are String!

I need to filter the records that contain array value `appt.date: "12/04/2020"`. Then find all distinct `appt.time` values for given date along with its count.

I tried to use the pipeline aggregation but just cannot get it to work. How can I solve this in **MongoDB 2.6.11**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try,

- `$match` `appt.date` condition to filter main document
- `$unwind` deconstruct `appt` array
- `$match` `appt.date` condition again to filter sub document
- `$group` by null and make time unique using `$addToSet` array
- `$addFields` to get count of total time

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { "appt.date": "12/04/2020" } },
  { $unwind: "$appt" },
  { $match: { "appt.date": "12/04/2020" } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      time: { $addToSet: "$appt.time" }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      time: 1,
      count: { $size: "$time" }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_hfQeiPbK-b)